# Appending an absolute positioned element

Tags: jquery

How can I position an element that is just appended? I've tried appending html with inline css (absolute + left) but the browser ignores the left css rule.

```
$(elem).append('<div class="x-tick" style="left: 10">'+dateStr+'</div>');
```

`x-tick` is position absolute.

Sorry the problem was I didn't include 'px' after number and I can't delete my question. Keep it real ya'll.

Comment: Can you show how you set styles?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the css for the class, and it should work. Something like this for absolute center the element:

```
.x-tick { position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%, -50%) }
```

And then you append the div with this class like you did above:

```
$(elem).append('<div class="x-tick">'+dateStr+'</div>');
```

For the inline css you will wrote something like this:

```
$(elem).append('<div class="x-tick" style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%, -50%)">'+dateStr+'</div>');
```